# C++ find std:string in std:wstring

Tags: c++

```
std::string targetDevice = "c53b1f8";
std::wstring devname;
VARIANT var;
var.vt = VT_BSTR;
pPropertyBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &var, 0);
devname = var.bstrVal;
VariantClear(&var);

if (devname.find(targetDevice) != std::string::npos) //<< my problem
{
...
}
```

What is the correct syntax for finding targetDevice in devname?

Comment: ```string``` to ```wstring``` cast?

Comment: I get an error no suitable conversion exists. Can you provide and example?

Comment: `devname.find(std::wstring(targetDevice.begin(), targetDevice.end())) != std::wstring::npos` should work, unless you have UTF-8 characters in `targetDevice`.

Comment: please provide more context what is your actual problem. Add also information which version of C++ you can use. Since you are saying something about path it is possible that `std::filesystem::path` (or boost version) can resolve your problem in nice clean way.

Comment: Wide strings are not recommended, they are clunky, non-portable and under-supported in C++. If you work exclusively with Windows, then (and probably only then) it might have sense to use wide strings, and then use them throughout your code. If you have any dreams of portability, it is probably wise to work in char and UTF-8 throughout, and only use wide strings at OS interface boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that different char size implies different character encoding.
What is worse `wchar_t` size is platform dependent.

But assuming that you are interested in ASCII characters only and most encodings are compatible with ASCII you can use STL algorithm to do that checking:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B>
bool contains(const A& a, const B& b)
{
     return std::search(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
                        std::begin(b), std::end(b)) != std::end(a);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x4bajr

---

you should edit your question and provide more context why you need this functionality, since I suspect there is better way to resolve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Windows only as `pPropertyBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &var, 0);` is a Windows Direct Show call, I decided to just make targetDevice a wstring as well.